# How to avoid instanceof?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anything wrong with instanceof checks here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204215/anything-wrong-with-instanceof-checks-here)

I have this code

```
public static int getNumberOfOwned(Player owner, String type){
    int count = 0;      
    for (Field f: board.fieldList)
        if (type == "Shipping" && f instanceof Shipping) 
            if (((Shipping)f).getOwnedBy() == owner)
                count++;
        else if (type == "Brewery" && f instanceof Brewery) 
            if (((Brewery)f).getOwnedBy() == owner)
                count++;
    return count;
}
```

I don't think this is very elegant and future proof. How can i avoid those instanceof operators.

Comment: not an answer, but your string comparision is wrong...

Comment: It's bad practice, but not necessarily wrong. Depends on where "type" come from for the compare. If it too is also a static string, this works. It's certainly not robust.

Comment: Is `getOwnedBy` defined in a common base class  or interface that is extended/implemented by both `Shipping` and `Brewery`?

Comment: @WillHartung - It would only be "not wrong" if there were watertight guarantees that `type` is *always* an interned String, and will always be ... in future versions.  Given how difficult it would be to provide those guarantees, an uncategorical "wrong" is the correct characterization.  (The tag "bad practice" is simply too weak for code that is broken or fragile 99.9% of the time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use an enum, and use a method on `Field` which returns the type. Here I'll go a little further and surmise that you *do not* want to update the count for certain types, so the enum is also "adorned" with a boolean expressing that:

```
enum FieldType {
    SHIPPING(true),
    BREWERY(true),
    NOTME(false);

    private final boolean countUpdate;

    FieldType(boolean countUpdate) { this.countUpdate = countUpdate; }
    public boolean mustUpdateCount() { return countUpdate; }
};

abstract class Field {
    protected final FieldType type;
    protected Field(FieldType type) { this.type = type; }
    public final FieldType getType() { return type; }
    public final boolean mustUpdateCount() { return type.mustUpdateCount(); }
}

class Brewery implements Field {
    Brewery() {
        super(BREWERY);
    }
}
```

and in your code:

```
FieldType expectedType = Enum.valueOf(type.toUpperCase());

for (Field f: board.fieldlist) {
    if (field.getType() != expectedType)
        continue;
    if (!f.getOwnedBy().equals(owner))
        continue;
    // Correct type, owned by the correct guy:
    // check that we must update; if so, update
    if (expectedType.mustUpdateCount())
        count++;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote if I may ask? This is a perfectly sensible solution.

Comment: +1 to make up for it. Seems proper to me. Someone did the same to my answer.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen : my intuition is that the OP does not want to update the count for certain field types, which means you define, for instance, `BREWERY(true)` as an enum, have a method in the enum return that boolean, and "forward" that method by a `final` method in the `Field` abstract class. Hence, you can just `if (thefield.hasToUpdate() && thefield.getOwner().equals(foo)) count++;` (post edited with that solution)

Comment: Nice... replacing the conditional with the polymorphic behaviour of the enum. Not my favourite solution, but an interesting one which addresses all my concerns. I rescind my -1.

Comment: ...now methods like `public final FieldType getType() { return type; }` become superfluous, but I'll draw the line at my criticism there ;)

Comment: And thanks, @fge, for being very open and receptive to criticism.

Comment: Remove `Field.mustUpdateCount()` and replace it with a call to `Field.getType().mustUpdateCount()`

Comment: @YanickRochon that could be a solution, of course, but the enum is pretty much "unifunctional" here. Unless the type is needed in other places (OP does not tell), I prefer this way of doing things. But that is a matter of taste.

Comment: @fge, if your `FieldType` enum of not much used elsewhere, then you could just have `Field` receive a `boolean` in the constructor (ie. `public Field(boolean mustUpdateCount)`) and remove the entire `enum` altogether. But you're right :) it's a matter of taste. **Update** : BTW, the original method has a `String type` parameter that you do not use in your solution anyway.

Comment: True. However, I would also see this enum as a base for `.toString()`. Whatever, this is becoming speculation here, we don't know what the OP really wants anyway :p (edit, I didn't see that, darn)

Answer (score 1):

Since `Shipping` and `Brewery` are derived from `Field`, `Field` could provide a getter that tells you its type, something like `getFieldType()`. When `Shipping` or `Brewery` are instantiated, they set the appropriate value, or you make `getFieldType()` abstract and have `Shipping` and `Brewery` implement them.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Answer (score 1):

Pass `Shipping.class` or `Brewery.class` to your function instead of a string representing the class and check that your Field belongs to that class:

```
public static int getNumberOfOwned(Player owner, Class<? extends Field> type){
    int count = 0;      
    for (Field f: board.fieldList) {
        if (type.isInstance(f) && f.getOwnedBy() == owner) {
            count++;
        }   
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: And what about `Brewery`?

Comment: Reworded it - the point was using a class instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to use the visitor pattern for this problem, you can look it up here: [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

At least it's the object oriented way of handling the problem, but it certainly needs more coding than your current solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add an "`isType(String type)`" method to Field. For that matter, add "`isOwnedBy(String owner)`" to Field as well.

```
for (Field f: board.fieldList)
    if (f.isType(type) && f.isOwnedBy(owner))
        count++;
return count;
```

Comment: Why isType() and isOwnedBy() as opposed to getType() and getOwner()?

Comment: I must say, isOwnedBy sounds much better than `owner == f.getOwner()`, even if it is less flexible. Also encapsulates the logic. Field doesn't _have_ a string type (what an icky thing for it to have), but it can check strings.

Answer (score 0):

first of all be advice you are using the "==" operator to test the equality of objects, this is most of the the times wrong, and definitely wrong in this case :)

If you want to determine if an object is of an particular type you could use the instanceof operator, see if they have the same class reference (here you could use the "==" operator) or try a cast and check for an exception, the last option is more of a fantasy because in the real world you should not try this.

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, but you could definitely tailor your objects to avoid the instanceof/class/cast stuff, something like:

```
class Foxtrot implements Sub {
    private  SubType type = SubType.ATACK;

    public SubType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}

interface Sub {
    enum SubType{ ATACK, BOOMER }

    public SubType getType();
}
```

And you can treat object as implementations of the Sub interface and check with their getType() method what kind they are, it should pretty much work.

Answer (score -1):

You should rewrite this code

1) 
class Field 
add method getType();

2) code:

```
public static int getNumberOfOwned(Player owner, String type){
  int count = 0;      
  for (Field f: board.fieldList){
    if (f.getType.equals(type)&& f.getOwnedBy().equesl(owner))
    count++;
  }
  return count;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Make `string getTypeString()` a property of Field, and avoid having a bunch of if statements (check `type.equals(f.getTypeString())`) Make getOwnedBy a property of Field, and don't use a cast. (fields that don't have owners can return null)